# Join sys.argv list items in Python

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to join sys.argv list items together with a space separator. I need to leave the first two indexes [0,1] and join up the rest into index [2] with a space between them. The sys.argv inputs are all strings too I don't get it. I am doing this inside a function is that it?

```
print(sys.argv)
elif len(sys.argv) > 3:
        print(len(sys.argv))
        sys.argv[2:(len(sys.argv)-1)] = [' '.join(sys.argv[2:(len(sys.argv)-1)])]
        print(sys.argv[2])
        print(sys.argv)
```

I keep getting this output:

```
['caesar.py', '46', 'chickens', 'room']
4
chickens
['caesar.py', '46', 'chickens', 'room']
```

What I need is this:

```
['caesar.py', '46', 'chickens', 'room']
4
chickens room
['caesar.py', '46', 'chickens room']
```

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Just use `print(' '.join(sys.argv[2:]))`

Comment: With a little bit of debugging you will find that you are replacing `['chickens']` by `[' '.join(['chickens'])]` and leave the rest alone.

Comment: Sorry everyone just figured it out, I had -1 with the length of the list that was causing it not to execute. Add more strings to the list to see. I hate maths haha

Comment: just saw these at the top thanks for the replies guys